# Kernel of tensor product map

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $K/F$ be a finite field extension and let $A$ and $B$ be finite-dimensional $K$ vector spaces. Let $\phi$ be the $F$-linear map
$\phi : A \otimes_{F} B \to A \otimes_{K} B$
taking $a\otimes_{F} b$ to $a\otimes_{K} b$.

Claim: The kernel of $\phi$ is the $F$ vector subspace $I$ generated by all elements $ca\otimes_{F} b - a\otimes_{F} cb$ with $a\in A$, $b \in B$, and $c\in K$.

I can see that $I$ is contained in the kernel of $\phi$ but why must the converse hold?

Comment: What's your definition of the tensor product?

Comment: Standard definition right? One with universal property.

Comment: **Hint:** $A$ is a direct sum of $n$ copies of $K$ and $B$ is the direct sum of $m$ copies of $K$. Both tensor products distribute over these sums, and the kernel of your map is the direct sum of the  kernels of the $nm$ summands. You therefore need to understand the case where $A=B=K$ (and check all those claims!). Now if $u$ is in the kernel of $K\otimes_FK\to K\otimes_K K=K$, which is just the map induced by multiplication, write $u=\sum_ia_i\otimes b_i$ and notice that $u=\sum_i(a_ib_i\otimes 1-a_i\otimes b_i)$.

Comment: Thanks Mariano this makes sense now.